# ubuntu 12.04 LTS wont recognize windows 7 for a dual boot

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning

Im trying to dual boot win 7 and ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop(asus u47), ive tried creating unallocated space in win 7 and creating a partition in ubuntu but it wants to unmount a previous partition (im assuming its talking about the c: drive in win 7), not sure if i should unmount it or not but i do not have a recovery disk for win 7 (and i do need win 7) so i do not want to risk losing it. Right now ive increased the size of c: drive so there is no unallocated space anymore. And as a side note I have tried this with ubuntu 12.10, still no recognition of win 7. My hard drive setup in the disk mng in win 7 is just c: drive and system reserved. Oh and fyi my tech level is average so im not that great at this stuff. And sorry if this has been asked before, But i never saw anything. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (The LTS stands for Long Term Support), as you appear to be new to Ubuntu, and 12.04 LTS is the most stable version.

What I think you need to do is put in the Windows disk, and create three partitions, one for Windows, one for Ubuntu, and one small 4gb one called a "swap space". Install Windows on one of them (not the swap space), and when that's done, put in your Ubuntu disk, and install Ubuntu on the partition that you haven't yet used.

Installing Ubuntu last should ensure that GRUB sees Windows as it's going in, so it will add it to the boot menu.

If you have any more questions, just ask.

Comment: ok i tried the 3 partitions thing, where i had 360 gig for my win, 100mb for sys recovery of win (that came with my laptop fyi) 4 gig of swap space and about 32o gig for ubuntu, the swap space and ubuntu space is not formated but is not free space or unallocated. and when i loaded the ubuntu 12.04 disk, it didnt recognize windows still, and when i hit something else and it pulls up the partition selection, it just has 750 gig of free space showing up (which is my whole hard drive), but it did not show the unmounting message this time. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

"Unmounting" a partition is non-destructive -- that term means that the partition is being made inaccessible to the currently-booted computer, but the partition won't be deleted or damaged in any way. Thus, if you're using the term correctly, you shouldn't be concerned about unmounting a partition.

That said, if you're using the term correctly, it's puzzling, since the Ubuntu installer does not, AFAIK, mount the Windows partition, much less unmount it, and it only unmounts the partition(s) it creates at the end of the installation process. Thus, I'm not sure what might be generating that message. I recommend you try again and report what happens with more precision. Describe everything you do in the step or two up to the message and take a screen shot, if necessary, so that you can report the exact wording of the message.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try the 3 partitions see if that works, and I was going to add screen shots of a couple of things including the unmount message, but askubuntu said that i needed a reputation of 30 or something similar